# TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property. [batche write, cloud firestore]

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

However this question exists from befor related to other language and frameworks.

But my problem is related to batch write of cloud firestore.

***TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property***. is the error when I execute the following code.

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
const batch = db.batch();

export default class App extends Component{

updateMultiDocsOnce(messages){
  try {

    let r = null;

    for (let i = messages.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

       r = db.collection("messages").doc(messages[i].id);

       batch.update(r, { sent: true, seen: true });

    }

    batch.commit();

   }catch (err) {
     console.log('----Error----', err);
   }

  }

  // another functions ......

}
```

I am using firestore docs, but here I dont know what went wrong with it.

Comment: Please make sure the code you provide is both minimal and complete/standalone. For example: what are `db` and `batch` defined/initialized as?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, please see the question again I have edited

Comment: Here I think the rror trigger with `batch.commit();`

Comment: I don't immediately see what could cause that error message. Can you reproduce it with a hardcoded array of message IDs (`messages` in your code)? If so, can you reproduce it with just a single message ID? Essentially: I'm trying to help you isolate the problem, in hopes that it'll help identify the cause.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you of ur help,
My Messages is:

```
[
{id: '39ieiddiewwwiie', text: 'Hi', date: new Date(), sent: false, seen: false},
{id: '39ieiddieieeeiwieeiie', text: 'How are you', date: new Date(), sent: false, seen: false},
{id: '39iei399eeiieddieiie', text: 'What are you doing', date: new Date(), sent: false, seen: false},
{id: '39ieiddieidkdkKDKDie', text: 'Are you doing something', date: new Date(), sent: false, seen: false}
]
```

Comment: Don't post comments with significant chunks of code/data please. Instead, use the edit link under your question to add the additional information directly in your question itself. But also note that I asked more concrete questions that help *you* pinpoint the problem, as Stack Overflow is an notoriously inefficient interactive debugger.

Comment: thank you @FrankvanPuffelen I completely skipped the batch operation, Now I am using the normal update within a loop may this works slow for a list of larg docs but for now I was not succed in using batch although I was using firestore docs.